# LAZY Fetching not working with ManyToMany relationship: Spring Boot and JPA

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, lazy-loading

I have the following scenario-
I have a many to many relationship between a **County** and a **Policy** entity.The relationship is maintained by an entity PolicyCounty. Here are the entity classes-

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name="policy_county")
public class PolicyCounty {


    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name="policy_county_id")
    private long policyStateId;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="policy_id")
    private InsurancePolicy policy;



    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "county_id")
    private County county;

    @Column(name="cost",nullable = false)
    private double cost;

}
```

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "insurance_policy")
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
public class InsurancePolicy {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name="policy_id")
    private long policyId;

    @Column(name="policy_name",nullable = false,unique = true)
    private String policyName;

    //Short description
    @Column(name="policy_description",nullable = false)
    private String policyDescription;

    //Long description
    @Column(name="choose_description",nullable = false)
    private String chooseDescription;


    //many policies can belong to one category
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "company_id", nullable = false)
    private Company company;

    //many policies can belong to one category
    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="category_id",nullable=false)
    private Category category;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "queriedPolices",fetch = FetchType.LAZY,cascade = {CascadeType.DETACH, CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.REFRESH})
    private Set<User> usersQueried=new HashSet<>();

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "policy", cascade = {CascadeType.MERGE,CascadeType.PERSIST,CascadeType.REMOVE},fetch = FetchType.LAZY, orphanRemoval = true)
    private Set<PolicyCounty> policyCounties = new HashSet<>();


}
```

```
@Entity
@Table(name="county")
public class County {

    @Id
    @Column(name="countyid")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long countyId;

    @Column(name="countyname",nullable = false,unique = true)
    private String countyName;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "adminId", nullable = false)
    private Admin admin;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "county", cascade = {CascadeType.MERGE,CascadeType.PERSIST,CascadeType.REMOVE},fetch = FetchType.LAZY,orphanRemoval = true) //orphan removal is set to true so that the relationship can be removed
    private Set<PolicyCounty> policyCounties = new HashSet<>();

    public County() {
    }

    public long getCountyId() {
        return countyId;
    }

    public String getCountyName() {
        return countyName;
    }

    @JsonIgnoreProperties("policyCounties") //This prevents the fetch of the admin when insurance policy getPolicyCounty is called, which results in unnecessary fetches of the admin, category and other related entities
    public Admin getAdmin() {
        return admin;
    }

    public Set<PolicyCounty> getPolicyCounties() {
        return policyCounties;
    }

    public void setCountyId(long countyId) {
        this.countyId = countyId;
    }

    public void setCountyName(String countyName) {
        this.countyName = countyName;
    }

    public void setAdmin(Admin admin) {
        this.admin = admin;
    }

    public void setPolicyCounties(Set<PolicyCounty> policyCounties) {
        this.policyCounties = policyCounties;
    }
}
```

Now, one of the requirements is to fetch the polices by category id. For this I write the method-

```
@Override
    public List<InsurancePolicyListDto> getAllInsurancePoliciesForCategory(long categoryId) {
        Category category=new Category();
        category.setCategoryId(categoryId);
        List<InsurancePolicy> insurancePolicies=this.insurancePolicyRepository.findAllByCategory(category);
        List<InsurancePolicyListDto> insurancePolicyDtos=new ArrayList<>();

        for(InsurancePolicy insurancePolicy: insurancePolicies){
            //converted manually to check for uncessary fetches which must be prevented
            InsurancePolicyListDto insurancePolicyListDto=new InsurancePolicyListDto();
            insurancePolicyListDto.setPolicyId(insurancePolicy.getPolicyId());
            insurancePolicyListDto.setPolicyName(insurancePolicy.getPolicyName());
            insurancePolicyListDto.setPolicyDescription(insurancePolicy.getPolicyDescription());
            insurancePolicyListDto.setChooseDescription(insurancePolicy.getChooseDescription());
            insurancePolicyListDto.setCompany(this.modelMapper.map(insurancePolicy.getCompany(), CompanyDetailsDto.class));
            Set<PolicyCounty> policyCounties=insurancePolicy.getPolicyCounties();
            insurancePolicyListDto.setPolicyCounties(this.countyToListDto(policyCounties));
            insurancePolicyDtos.add(insurancePolicyListDto);
        }
        return insurancePolicyDtos;
    }
```

**Problem-**
I run my project in debug mode and when the line-
`Set<PolicyCounty> policyCounties=insurancePolicy.getPolicyCounties();` is executed, I get unexpected fetches from the database. **According to my understanding only the PolicyCounty entities and County entities must be fetched without fetching the Admin details from the county entity (I have used LAZY fetch type for admin in county.)** But, what I get is all the admin details, other associated entities of the admin which are not even requried and should have been fetched lazily.
Thus, I am not able to understand why even after FetchType.LAZY for admin, I am getting all the details from the admin table and its other related tables.
I added @JsonIgnoreProperties in the county class getAdmin() which works when @Getter and @Setter are used but does not work when getters and setters have been created manually in InsurancePolicy and PolicyCounty classes.
Please help me understand why Lazy fetching is failing in this case and that to for all the related entities of admin by just calling
`Set<PolicyCounty> policyCounties=insurancePolicy.getPolicyCounties();`. Please help!

Answer (score 0):

You have to exclude admin entity from being serialized. For that you can use
@JsonView or @JsonIdentityInfo annotations.

For reference : https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-bidirectional-relationships-and-infinite-recursion

Comment: Can you please tell why Lazy Loading is not working. I am getting repeated fetches in a cycle. Why FetchType.LAZY is not working in this case.

Comment: The actual loading will happen when you call a method on the returned object. And if you don't have huge number of elements in your collection you can change **LAZY** to **EAGER** so that the provider loads the objects.

Comment: I am getting the queries showing that admin, company, and other assocated entities are getting fetched when getPolicyCounties() method is invoked. It should only fetch the PolicyCounty but is fetching the InsurancePolicy->Company->Admin entities also.

Comment: @coder001 in lazy loading mapping entity will not fetch until you explicitly call it. In your case you get (insurancePolicy.getPolicyCounties())  all PolicyCounties from the insurance policy so internally it will call the get method for Admin object that's why it return it.

Comment: If you want to get some fields from that entity object you need to create DTOs with required fields having the same name as in entity. and use BeanUtils class for copy the properties which has the same field name.

Comment: ' @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(name="query_policy_county",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="query", referencedColumnName = "query_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="policy_county", referencedColumnName = "policy_county_id"))'  Yes you said it right, but my InsurancePolicyEntity does not directly have Admin. It has a Category (with lazy fetch)  and the category has a Admin(with lazy fetch), but when I just want to fetch the PolicyCounties, I also get the Company and Admin.

Comment: I also tried using FetchType.LAZY on the policy and county of the PolicyCounty class, but still getting same issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you are still facing the same issue it might be happened beacuse you are not accessing it in **TransactionalContext** please try **@Transactional** at the method level.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, but I figured out the reason was the @Data annotation of the lombok. It causes the trouble and might trigger getters even with lazy loading.

Answer (score 0):

It may give you an idea. I solved my issue in this way.

```
@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinTable(name = "your_join_table_name", ...)
private Set<OtherEntity> relatedEntities;
```